# After CiviCRM 5.65.1 upgrade, Contributions tab is blank but contributions show up in Activities tab

Tags: civicontribute, upgrade

Just upgraded to CiviCRM 5.65.1 and now when I open contacts who I know have contributions, the tab shows the number of contributions, but the box below the tab that should list the contributions is blank and I get an error:
"Unable to reach the server. Please refresh this page in your browser and try again."

The contributions show up in the Activities tab instead.

Anyone else having this problem?

Also I dug around in my PHP error log and found these two critical errors:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Civi\Api4\PaymentProcessor' not found in /home/footprk1/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Page/PaymentProcessor.php:65

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Civi\Api4\ContributionPage' not found in /home/footprk1/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php:1579

[image: screenshot_contributions]

[image: screenshot_activities]

Comment: By any chance do you have any extensions installed, especially an extension that has to do with contributions?

Comment: I have several: Stripe Payment Processor, IATS Payments, Contribution cancel actions, Payment Shared, Omnipay multiprocessor support.

Comment: Also, see separate post I made regarding fatal PHP errors I found in the debug.log -  probably connected to this problem: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/45554/after-upgrade-to-5-65-php-fatal-error-missing-paymentprocessor-and-contribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try enabling Civi contribute extension from the Extension page if its not already installed

Comment: Yes, that was it!! THANK YOU!!!