# After upgrade to 5.65 PHP fatal error: Missing PaymentProcessor and ContributionPage classes?

Tags: civicontribute, upgrade

Various problems with Contribution pages and payment processors since upgrading to CiviCRM 5.65 (from 5.49). In the PHP error log I see:

PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Civi\Api4\PaymentProcessor' not found in /home/footprk1/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Page/PaymentProcessor.php:65

PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Civi\Api4\ContributionPage' not found in /home/footprk1/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php:1579

I'm noticing that these classes seem to have moved from plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4 to plugins/civicrm/civicrm/ext/civi_contribute/Civi/Api4.  Seems like maybe the system is still looking in the old directory for these classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that all the new core extensions (at Administer - System Settings - Extensions) are enabled for their corresponding components. e.g. if you have the CiviContribute component enabled, then the civi_contribute extension should also be enabled. If it didn't get enabled during upgrade then the upgrade didn't go properly.

Comment: YES, that was it. THANK YOU!!